# How to create an Arrayformula for combining multiple values in columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a sheet ([shared here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a6y72FsXw-YetW91FQ9grrkH9XP2Gv7ciTVCED6do1o/edit#gid=0)) where I am trying to produce an age range based on combining values in two columns (age minimum, age maximum).

- If both age minimum and age maximum are specified, I want to combine both values with a dash in the middle I.e. "10-15"
- If no age minimum is specified, I want to display: "0-{age maximum}"  I.e.  "0-15"
- If no age maximum is specified, I want to display: "{age minimum}+"  I.e. "18+"

**Problem #1**: I built the below formula, which mostly works, but produces a dash "-" in the empty cells. I need to have blank cells when there is no age data specified.

```
=if(and(A2<>"",B2=""),A2&"+",if(and(A2="",B2<>""),"0-"&B2,(A2&"-"&B2)))
```

**Problem#2**: I need to wrap this in an arrayformula, so I don't have to manually copy and paste the formula when new rows are added, but my attempt (below) does not produce the desired results (see Age range (arrayformula) column):

```
=arrayformula(if(and($A2:$A<>"",$B2:$B=""),$A2:$A&"+",if(and($A2:$A="",$B2:$B<>""),"0-"&$B2:$B,($A2:$A&"-"&$B2:$B))))
```

I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to complex formulas, so I greatly appreciate the help  . thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question:

```
=arrayformula(IF(LEN($A2:A) + LEN($B2:B) = 0,,(if(($A2:$A<>"")*($B2:$B=""),$A2:$A&"+",if(($A2:$A="")*($B2:$B<>""),"0-"&$B2:$B,($A2:$A&"-"&$B2:$B))))))
```